# Making particle system single user?

Tags: particles, hair, instances

When i duplicate a particle system or the object containing the particle system, blender seems to only instance it. I tried to make it a single user by selecting Object>Relations>Make Single User>Object & Data, but that only makes the modifier container single, not the particle system itself? Am i missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, i found it. Make a new preset of the particle system:

[image]

Coming from other 3D programs, some concepts of blender really need quite a while to get used to.